# Unclear about the [search_mode] usage in XLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, xlookup

I have two tabs in a sheet
From below people sheet , we may have same person with multipole location ,
[image]

In another sheet I need to pull the latest location the person .
Like when I lookup the name , I need to show the MMM location on the basis of latest Report Date .

As I used the XLOOKUP , it pulls ggg instead of MMM . I dont know how I force it to sort the last to first .

[image]

Here in this case it should show MMM not the ggg.
[image]

Anyone please help this lookup .

Comment: I don't think when there are multiple records for an instance a regular lookup function is going to work, you need to use either `INDEX()` & `FILTER()` Function or `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()` . Any lookup function shall bring the first instances only when there is a duplicate.

Comment: Actually XLOOKUP has a feature to either start from the top or the bottom. It would be useful if the actual formula used is posted. It may be that the last instance of `TEST` has a space behind it, or the lookup range is insufficient.